# Extracting Country name and year from column and create a new columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In a situation below:

| Source | Value |
| --- | --- |
| sx_India-2021 | 23 |
| dfr_Australia-1987 | 21 |
| df_fg-Africa-2022 | 34 |

I have used "str.split" but it is not working for all the records. I need a separate column-"country" and "Year" from "Source".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

```
df[['Country', 'Year']] = pd.DataFrame(df['Source'].str.split(r'[_-]').str[-2:].tolist())
print(df)

# Output
               Source  Value    Country  Year
0       sx_India-2021     23      India  2021
1  dfr_Australia-1987     21  Australia  1987
2   df_fg-Africa-2022     34     Africa  2022
```

Use:

```
pat = r'[_-](?P<Country>[^-]*)-(?P<Year>\d{4})'
df = pd.concat([df, df['Source'].str.extract(pat)], axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
               Source  Value    Country  Year
0       sx_India-2021     23      India  2021
1  dfr_Australia-1987     21  Australia  1987
2   df_fg-Africa-2022     34     Africa  2022
```

If you don't need `Source` column, use:

```
df = pd.concat([df.pop('Source').str.extract(pat), df], axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
     Country  Year  Value
0      India  2021     23
1  Australia  1987     21
2     Africa  2022     34
```

Comment: In theory one could use `str.rsplit` with a regex, however I get an error with `df['Source'].str.rsplit(r'[-_]', n=2, regex=True)` (pandas 1.4.1). Do you also have it?

Comment: Unfortunately `rsplit` has a bug with `regex`. I experienced it many times from past versions....... That's why I used `str.extract`.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29633

Comment: Yes me too, `rsplit` would be the logical way otherwise

Comment: Weird, given `regex` parameter was added in 1.4.0

Comment: @mozway. I'm agree with you. I updated my answer with `str.split`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could use `str.extract`:

```
df['Source'].str.extract(r'([^-_]+)-\d+$', expand=False)
```

output:

```
0        India
1    Australia
2       Africa
Name: Source, dtype: object
```

for both Country and Year:

```
df[['Country', 'Year']] = df['Source'].str.extract('([^-_]+)-(\d+)$')
```

output:

```
               Source  Value    Country  Year
0       sx_India-2021     23      India  2021
1  dfr_Australia-1987     21  Australia  1987
2   df_fg-Africa-2022     34     Africa  2022
```

Comment: I do not know why but I am getting 'NAN' for the country and year column.